# How to create node http proxy pointing to bluehost subfolder?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I have a [blog here](http://69.195.124.88/~crowdfoo/blogbeaconboss/).

And this is what I do:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy'); 
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.get("/blog/", function(req, res){ 
    apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://69.195.124.88/~crowdfoo/blogbeaconboss/:80' });
});
```

But it says:

> 404: File Not Found

When I open:
http://www.example.com/blog/ on production or http://localnode.com:3000/blog/ on local machine where localnode is localhost

Would appreciate help in this,
Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, have you pointed www.example.com to localhost, is that why you are using www.example.com?

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost, updated question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I think part of the problem might be that you're trying to include the path in your proxy URL. I tried this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.use('/', function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://69.195.124.88'
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

And now I can see your blog at http://localhost:3000/~crowdfoo/blogbeaconboss/ without any issue.

**/Edit**

You should probably remove the port number `:80` at the end of your URL. Try this URL instead:

```
http://69.195.124.88/~crowdfoo/blogbeaconboss/
```

Note that the port should be attached to the hostname, not after the path like you had it. If you wanted to specify the port it would look like this:

```
http://69.195.124.88:80/~crowdfoo/blogbeaconboss/
```

But this is redundant, the `http` URL scheme means use port 80 if its left unspecified.

Comment: tried without port and with port after hostname, still 404 :(

Comment: Re:edit 
The thing is that there are multiple blogs hosted on this IP, they are located in subfolders